# Exact meaning of "You are brand new"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives, adverbs, brands

I run across a phrase of "You are brand new to GitHub" on the web.

What makes me confused is the word "brand"; is it a noun, an adjective or an adverb?

Comment: The perfectly pedestrian adjective *brand-new* should be any possible dictionary. Voting to close as general reference.

Comment: "Brand-new": " : fresh from the manufacturer : conspicuously new and unused" (MW3UDE). This is a standard English idiom. See the e. e. cummings poem "[she being brand new]()http://writersalmanac.publicradio.org/index.php?date=2002/10/14".

Comment: Brand new: [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brand%2Bnew?q=brand+new), [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brand%20new), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brand_new).

Comment: According to ODO, _brand_ here is half an adjective.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brand_new http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brand-new  Voting to close as GR.

Comment: "You are brand new to GitHub" is not quite an appropriate use of the phrase "brand new".

Comment: Relevant, maybe? [Etymolonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=brand+new&searchmode=none) claims that the expression "brand new" must have originally meant "fresh from the fire," and mentions that Shakespeare uses "fire-new".

Comment: @tchrist the question is as to the grammatical function of *brand*, not strictly about the meaning of *brand-new*. hastily closed.

Comment: @Kris Sure it is.  What is it you are thinking is wrong with it?

Comment: @jlovegren ODO maintains that the adjective is _brand new_, which, if one accepts their view (that _brand new_ is a compound adjective) makes the question the same as "What part of speech is _particle_ in _particleboard_?:

Comment: @EdwinAshworth consider the following usage: "[BRAND BRAND NEW (KING KOIL ) BOX SPRING TWIN SIZE](http://alberta.kijiji.ca/c-buy-and-sell-furniture-beds-mattresses-BRAND-BRAND-NEW-KING-KOIL-BOX-SPRING-TWIN-SIZE-W0QQAdIdZ446514811)" where *brand* is reduplicated to emphasize the degree of newness (as in *very very*, *quite very*, etc.). do you find usages such as *particle particle board* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*brand* is a degree word. Degree words modify adjectives to describe the degree to which a property is had. The adjective *new* is special in that one usually says **brand new** instead of **very new**.

Comment: What other words (besides *new*) does *brand* work with?

Comment: @PeterShor Spanking.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I've read dialogues in which speakers have said "That's brand clean!"

Comment: @StoneyB Can you **really** say that something is *brand spanking*, not just that it is *brand spanking new*?  It looks like all the OED’s citations of this kind of *spanking* meaning *very* occur in phrases like *spanking new* or *brand spanking new*, but that there are none for just *brand spanking* alone without the *new*.  What does that say or suggest then?

Comment: @tchrist: I wonder if StoneyB meant to answer the question, "What other words (besides _brand_) works with _new_ that way?"

Comment: I don't know whether you can call something a "degree word" if it can only modify one adjective.

Comment: That's its function. It's a bit strange using an intensifier with _new_ anyway, a word which has at least one foot in the absolute (in the sense of an extreme) camp. Arguably, something is either new or not new. _Not new_ **is** gradable (almost new, fairly new, not so new ...). It's probably best to consider _brand new_ as a compound adjective (the hyphenated form is often used anyway). And concede that _new_ is now used rather loosely, to include _newish_.

Comment: @Edwin: unless you consider something to be *new* only at the instant of its creation, and say that it becomes *old* a millisecond thereafter, I think you have to accept that *new* is gradable. Something can be *"relatively new*". I don't think anything can be *"relatively perfect"* (although that doesn't stop everybody from using it).